# Overload abstract methods in abstract class

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class, overloading, abstract-methods

I want to have an abstract class that has an abstract method, say `abstract void compare()`. But the parameters it takes should vary according to different implementations in different subclasses. I wonder what is the right way to do this?

I cannot overload it by writing different signatures of it in the abstract class itself, because if I do so, any of its subclasses would need to implement all the versions, which is not what I want. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming that each version of `compare()` will all have the same number of parameters (which they should), you could use generics so that subclasses can define what the types of the parameters are.

```
abstract <I, J> void compare(I arg1, J arg2);
```

Comment: If OP takes this path, he should read through [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Comment: Note that this is the only way to do this, different numbers of arguments would defeat the point of defining an interface.

Comment: @AdrianLeonhard I suppose your correct. The only way for OP to make it take more arguments would be to wrap them in a separate class. The method signature would still be the same though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But in my case, some implementations do have different number of parameters. So I suppose I should just use normal super class instead of abstract ones and write all the signatures there? Thanks.

Comment: @JFreebird yes, in that case, your methods don't have enough in common to be combined into an abstract one.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Generics to do it :

```
public abstract class AbstractClass<T>{
public abstract void compare(T element);
}
```

And in the implementation you write this :

```
Public class MyImpl extends AbstractClass<SpecificType>{
public void compare(SpecificType elemental{
// do stuff
}
}
```